# Implementing Gridstack 3 in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, gridstack

I'm following [this example](https://gridstackjs.com/#getStarted), trying to implement it in Angular.

I import as follows (no jQuery dependencies):

```
import * as GridStack from 'gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5';
```

And the code

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    
  var items = [
      {content: 'my first widget'}, // will default to location (0,0) and 1x1
      {w: 2, content: 'another longer widget!'} // will be placed next at (1,0) and 2x1
   ];

    var grid = GridStack.init();
    grid.load(items);
}
```

But all I see is static divs instead of a grid, and there are no errors. What's missing?

Comment: <link href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> ?

Comment: I have that, doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post your HTML template.

Double check your config from [GridStack Read Me](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/blob/develop/README.md#install), if you are using an `ngfor` then you need to see step 3 and invoke this on your main div `$('.grid-stack').gridstack();`

> 1. You must `install`:

---

```
yarn add gridstack
// or
npm install --save gridstack
```

> 2. You must `import` it into angular component **2A** or 2B for HTML:

---

- **2A** For your answer `Typescript` like so:

```
import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css';
import GridStack from 'gridstack';
```

*You should now have* `gridstack-h5.js` [gridstack native js version like here](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gridstack@4.0.3/dist/gridstack-h5.js)

- **2B** For others lookging to do it in `HTML` *optional*, like so:

  `<script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>`

  `<link href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

> 3. What is your HTML template, like [here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/105#issuecomment-580961102)

---

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('.grid-stack').gridstack();
            this.gridStack = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');
        }, 300); //This MUST finish after dynamic data is retrieved for ngfor, and calling these statements in another area just doesn't work
    }
```

Comment: Am I forced to use jQuery? The idea of Gridstack 3 is to eliminate the dependency

Comment: if you look at my post, you will see three options in step 4 this is native but also very new `import 'gridstack/dist/h5/gridstack-dd-native';` . So, to test I would try the other two imports as well one at a time.

Comment: meanwhile Gridstack is JQuery free, please look at https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/blob/develop/README.md#requirements

Comment: if you use the option I mentioned above in step 4

Comment: I did not understand why the scripts property has to reference jquery. 
The question is about implementation without jquery. Can you make an example jquery free?

Comment: It does not , please see my answer again. I just gave an option if they wanted to use jquery to support legacy... I will update it to clarify. you only need 1) `import 'gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css';` /`<link href="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` & if depending on if you need Drag and Drop *OR* Static grid... `import 'gridstack/dist/h5/gridstack-dd-native';` or for html link ``<script src="node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-static.js"></script> hope it helps

Comment: Why are we using a settimeout here @Transformer? Adding a settimeout seems like a hack to me.